# Can I hack together a scanner driver for Win2K3 from XP, Vista, 2008 and 98 versions?

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have a multifunction scanner/printer/copier which I am moving to Windows Server 2003 but I cannot find a specific scanner driver for Win2K3. There are drivers for every other platform and I'm wondering what others have done in this situation. Has anyone hacked a scanner driver together from the other platforms or is there a fantastic generic TWAIN driver?

The model of the device is SCX4100 which is a Samsung.

[Versions of scanner drivers](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/download/supportDown.do?group=printsolutions&type=printsolutions&subtype=colourmultiprinter&model_nm=SCX-4100&disp_nm=SCX-4100&language=&cate_type=all&dType=D&mType=DR&vType=&prd_ia_cd=06010100&model_cd=&menu=download)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The times I've had to install a driver on Server2003, I just tried the Server2000 driver.  Most times it works out for the majority (or all) of the functionality.

Comment: I have also had success stealing drivers from windows 2000 for various hardware.

Comment: I'll vote this as the answer because it will probably work for most people, but does not work for my scanner. I'll have to upgrade to Win 2008.